# Silverstripe get the last 8 items by date and display them in reverse order

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

I'm a beginner in PHP and Silverstripe so I apologise if the question has a very simple answer.
I'm trying to get the last 8 items by date from a list of gigs and display them in reverse (ascending) order. here's my code:

```
//my php function
function Tour() {
      if(!isset($_GET['start']) || !is_numeric($_GET['start']) || (int)$_GET['start'] < 1) $_GET['start'] = 0;
      $SQL_start = (int)$_GET['start'];
      $doSet = DataObject::get(
        $callerClass = "GigDetail",
        $filter = "",
        $sort = "Date ASC",
        $join = "",
        $limit = "{$SQL_start},8"
      );

      return $doSet ? $doSet : false;
    }

//my ss file
<% control Tour %>
    <p>$Place - $Date.Nice - $Address <a href="$Link">more &raquo;</a></p>
<% end_control %>
```

This will show them in reverse order but from the bottom of the list. while I want to get the latest 8 gigs by date and display them in reverse order. Does it have anyting to do with $_GET['start'] ?

Thanks in advance
Mauro

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Silverstripe 3 you can reverse DataLists in the control loop like so:

**PHP**

```
function Tour() {
    $gigSet = GigDetail::get()->sort("Date DESC")->limit(8);

    return $gigSet ? $gigSet : false;
}
```

**Template**

```
<% loop $Tour.Reverse %>
    <p>$Place - $Date.Nice - $Address <a href="$Link">more &raquo;</a></p>
<% end_loop %>
```

More info:
http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/reference/templates

Comment: Shouldn't that be `loop` instead of `control` in the template?

Comment: @bummzack Either will work, but yes you are right, it should be loop instead of control. I was using the code from the original post. I've edited my answer to use loop as you have suggested. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Define your model with a function in it:

```
class Gig extends DataObject {
    static $db = array(
        'SomeField' => 'Text',
        'Date' => 'Date'
     );
}

class Gig_Controller extends Controller {
        public function Tour() {
            return Gig::get()->sort('Date ASC')->limit(8);
        }
}
```

Don't ever use PHP $_GET variables directly in this manner, as you'll open your applications up to SQL injection attacks. In Silverstripe, classes that extend the controller can use `$this->getRequest()->requestVar('varName')`, which will sanitize GET and POST variables for you.